# Testing for connectivity not working properly

Tags: java, android, networking, mobile

Before doing networking connection stuff I use this code to set connectivity. If it is `NONE` it's not possible, displaying an error. Now I am getting lots of user reports of user complaning about this error message, telling me that they are able to use the internet on other apps.

```
final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork == null || !activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        newNetworkType = NetworkStatus.NONE;
} else {
        if (activeNetwork.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) {
                newNetworkType = NetworkStatus.LOW;
        } else {
                newNetworkType = NetworkStatus.HIGH;
        }
}
```

This code is hooked to a NetworkChangedReceiver, updating it constantly. Now I am wondering if this code is not working properly. Should I rely on other methods? For instance does `activeNetwork == null` really mean that there is no internet connection? Should I maybe use `NetworkInfo.isAvailable` instead of `isConnected`? What about `isConnecting?`

Answer (score 1):

Well I had many issues with this code. Hence I opted for a different route completely.

What I do is, I ping the website which I'm going to communicate with.
It helps in two things

a) To check the condition of your internet
b) Is your website online or not

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL u = new URL("http://www.yourwebsite.com/");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    // You can determine on HTTP return code received. 200 is success.
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```